# How to handle back button in rails quiz application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, back

I have a quiz game in ruby on rails. Every page loads a single question, records the response and proceeds. How can I prevent the user from going back in the browser and changing the response?

Comment: can you paste the relevant part of your code?

Comment: you can set up rules in the model so that the same user cannot answer the same question twice. that way even if they go back to the question, when they try and submit it again there will be an error